# Запись изображения в ZIP архив Java

Tags: java, изображения, zip

Имеется код

```
try(ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(".\\output.zip"));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("https://static9.depositphotos.com/1594308/1110/i/600/depositphotos_11107478-stock-photo-fantasy.jpg")){
        ZipEntry entry1 = new ZipEntry("image.jpg");
        zout.putNextEntry(entry1);
        // считываем содержимое файла в массив byte
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(buffer);
        // добавляем содержимое к архиву
        zout.write(buffer);
        // закрываем текущую запись для новой записи
        zout.closeEntry();
    }
```

Необходимо загрузить изображение(известен ее URL адрес) в архив. В потоковых классах пока что не очень шарю. Не понимаю логику загрузки изображения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы были близки к истине, только FileInputStream не предназначен для скачивания по урлу. Попробуйте так:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String FILE_URL = "https://static9.depositphotos.com/1594308/1110/i/600/depositphotos_11107478-stock-photo-fantasy.jpg";        
        downloadToZip(FILE_URL, "output.zip", "image.jpg");        
    }

    public static void downloadToZip (String fileUrl, String targetName, String targetFileName) throws IOException {
        try (ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetName));
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(fileUrl).openStream())) {
            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(targetFileName));
            copy(is, zout);
            zout.closeEntry();
        }
    }

    private static void copy(InputStream source, OutputStream target) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = source.read(buf)) > 0) target.write(buf, 0, length);
    }

}
```

Comment: Все работает, только качество изображения низкое, при попытки загрузки изображение большего разрешения, так вообще 1/10 часть только загрузилась, остальное серым цветом залито. Не знаете в чем может быть причина? Будто изображение не полностью загружается.

Comment: is.available() должен выводить доступное количество байт, т.е. должно быть равно размеру изображения, в моем случае программы выдает 16КБ, когда как источник "весит" 254КБ. Получается InputStream не все считывает или что?

Comment: @A.Fatkullin все дело в том, что вы некорректно выполняете копирование из InputStream в OutputStream, я отредактировал ответ, сделал все на чистом коре, чтобы вы могли разобраться. вместе с тем, для подобного копирования (из стрима в стрим) существует довольно много интсрументов, например в спринге или в апачевских или гугловых утилитах, где все выполняется вызовом одноно метода с передачей в аргументы двух стримов